# How do I copy the strings in a vector<pair<string, int>> to vector<string>?

Tags: c++, vector, boost, transform, push-back

I'm using GCC 9.2.0 and boost 1.55.

I have 2 vectors:

```
vector< pair< string, int > > source;
vector< string > dest;
```

I need to transform the `source` vector to the `dest`, such that it should contain only `string` elements of `source` vector.

Is it possible using `boost::push_back` and adaptors?

```
boost::range::push_back( dest, source | /* adaptor ??? */ );
```

Currently I have this workable code, but it should be changed:

```
transform( source.begin(), source.end(), back_inserter(dest), __gnu_cxx::select1st< std::pair< std::string, int > >() );
```

Comment: Should be a prime example for ranges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To continue the trend of posting mimimal improvements:

**[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/o5Wh7o)**

```
#include <boost/range/adaptor/map.hpp>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>

using namespace std::string_literals;
using namespace boost::adaptors;

template <typename R>
auto to_vector(R const& range) {
    return std::vector(boost::begin(range), boost::end(range));
}

int main() {
    std::vector source {std::pair {"one"s,1},{"two",2},{"three",3}};

    fmt::print("keys {}\nvalues {}\n",
            source | map_keys,
            source | map_values);
    
    // if you really need the vectors
    auto keys   = to_vector(source | map_keys);
    auto values = to_vector(source | map_values);
}
```

Prints

```
keys {"one", "two", "three"}
values {1, 2, 3}
```

Comment: Perfect, map_keys adaptor is exactly what I was looking for!!!

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) and [`std::back_inserter`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter) with a lambda instead:

```
#include <algorithm> // transform
#include <iterator>  // back_inserter

std::transform(source.begin(), source.end(), std::back_inserter(dest),
               [](auto& p) {
                   return p.first;
               });
```

Comment: Sure, thanks. I just want to know is it possible to 'simplify' this line to use boost algorithms

Comment: @AlexandrDerkach I'm not 100% sure but this may be one of the boost algorithms that's found its way into the standard.

Comment: Yeah, probably it already can be in standard library.

Comment: @AlexandrDerkach, give a look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65793995/5825294).

Comment: I really need to start learning these ranges thingies ... Looks nice.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, the chapter on ranges from [Functional Programming in C++](https://livebook.manning.com/book/functional-programming-in-c-plus-plus/about-this-book/) is for free, iIcr.

Comment: @Enlico Thanks! Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a boost solution with the `transformed` adaptor:

```cpp
#include <boost/range/adaptor/transformed.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

using boost::adaptors::transformed;

// define function object (so we can pass it around) emulating std::get
template<std::size_t N>
auto constexpr get = [](auto const& x){ return std::get<N>(x); };

int main()
{
    // prepare sample input
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string,int>> source{{"one",1},{"two",2},{"three",3}};

    // the line you look for
    auto dest = source | transformed(get<0>);

    // dest is a vector on which we can iterate
    for (auto const& i : dest) {
        std::cout << i << '\n';
    }

    // if you really need it to be a vector
    auto dest_vec = boost::copy_range<std::vector<std::string>>(dest);
}
```

Comment: This this similar to what i was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: This is nice. I made [a C++20 version](https://godbolt.org/z/aKeorn). Is it possible to get a `std::vector<std::string>` directly out of the transformation? This `dest` is `const` if I'm not mistaken?

Comment: @TedLyngmo, `dest` is a view. And you can get an actual vector via `boost::copy_range`. Please, see my change.

Comment: Nice. `std::vector<std::string> dest_vec(dest.begin(), dest.end());` seems to work too. You got my vote :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo, in that case you are calling directly the overload number 5 of [`std::vector<>::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector). `boost::copy_range` seems to do something similar, even though it relies on `boost::begin`/`boost::end`.

Comment: @Enlico Yes, that's the one I like. I use it whenever possible.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, you got mine too.

Comment: Boost has more convenience than that! https://godbolt.org/z/o5Wh7o (/cc @TedLyngmo opted to [post as another contender](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65796079/85371)

Comment: @sehe Briliant! It's not often I've upvoted a question, provided an answer and upvoted _all_ the other answers :-) I learned a lot by you all.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution using the range-v3 library:

```
auto dest = source 
          | ranges::views::keys 
          | ranges::to<std::vector<std::string>>;
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/5MzhWq).

---

In C++20, there's no `std::ranges::to`, but you can still copy over the keys to `dest` if it already exists:

```
std::ranges::copy(source | std::views::keys, 
                  std::back_inserter(dest));
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/7xdoq5).

Note that this doesn't work in Clang trunk, which I assume is a bug.

Comment: Yet another nice one - Here's [my C++20 attempt](https://godbolt.org/z/8aK4xP) - I couldn't find the standard version of `ranges::to` though and I also tried using `fmt::print` from `<format>` but it seems neither `g++` nor `clang++` have a `<format>` header yet.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Nice :) Yeah, no one has implemented `<format>` yet. I actually wanted to post a solution that used `std::ranges::copy` to fill up `dest`, but couldn't get it to work. I meant to write a question about it, but got sidetracked. Thanks for the comment, it reminded me :) btw, `std::views` is shorthand for `std::ranges::views`, so that's a few characters less out of the box.

Comment: You're welcome :-) I found why I couldn't find `ranges::to`: [A Plan for C++23 Ranges - P2214r0 - View adjuncts](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p2214r0.html#view-adjuncts): "_One critical piece of missing functionality is `ranges::to` [[P1206R1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p2214r0.html#ref-P1206R1)]._"

Comment: @TedLyngmo Hmm, it does work in GCC, but not in Clang. I assume it's a Clang bug, so I've updated a solution with C++20 ranges as well.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Oh yeah, I was quite disappointed when `to` didn't make it into C++20 :( But we can't have all the goodies at once, I guess :p